# Solving for power of a non linear equation in matlab

Tags: matlab, equation-solving, exponent

I have been trying to solve for n in the equation given below in matlab. All the rest of the values are known :
H_obs = 1*61 vector, dhdx = 1*61 vector, a = 1*61 vector. All the values of all the vectors are known

```
    a = (2*(10^-25)/(n+2))*((918*3.71)^n)*(H_obs.^(n+2))*(abs(dhdx).^(n-1))*dhdx;
```

Any tips on how to solve?
TIA

Comment: First factor has (n+2) in denominator and rest have it in exponent?

Comment: Since you have 61 equations and 1 unknown, what you have is an overdetermined system - which means that you're not _solving_ it, but rather _finding an optimal solution_ in some sense. Take a look [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/index.html).

Comment: @hazeiio : Yep.

Comment: @Dev-iL : Thanks. That's exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: Since it is nonlinear equation, you can use `fsolve` from Optimization Toolbox. You can find additional information on how to use it here: [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html)

Comment: @hazeiio : Thanks. Will look into it. Was actually wondering how to go about solving it, making the objective function and solving for n using fsolve or fminunc.